# How to get element from a DIV container by points in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website, touch-event

I have created a 5 number of DIV's in a ".container" DIV element like bellow;

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="elem1">No 1</div>
   <div class="elem2">No 2</div>
   <div class="elem3">No 3</div>
   <div class="elem4">No 4</div>
   <div class="elem5">No 5</div>
</div>
```

*touchstart*, *touchmove* and *touchend* event has assigned to the `.container` element.

On touch start of the container in `.elem1`, the *touchstart* event handler receive "elem1" in the `event.target`.

On touch end of the container in '.elem4' the *touchend* event handler receive "elem1" in the `event.target` but I am release touch in **elem4**. This is the problem. I need to get *elem4* here.

How to I get the exact element on the *touchend* event handler? Any solution / suggestion on this by using touch points?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery to listen for your touch events? I would do something similar to this: [JSFiddle](http://bit.ly/197Fhxl). Essentially, I'm listening for touch events on the *touch* class itself, then pulling the specific data from the ID. You could substitute anything for the ID, be it a data-attribute or the innerHTML. Event bubbling can get hairy and this solution has worked for me in the past.

P.S. Did you know you can now emulate touch events in Google Chrome? [Check out this page!](http://bit.ly/GGIRWJ)

Answer (score 0):

use `event.pageX`, `event.pageY`, `document.elementFromPoint` in the following way:

```
$('.container').bind('touchend', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(ev.pageX, ev.pageY);
});
```

i made an example of this idea here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MPn3L/

(note that i simulated the `mouseup` event, but it works the same with `touchend` on touch devices)

that's the best solution i can think of.